# Ubuntu / node.js dropping incoming requests

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, node.js

I am getting dropped requests on a node.js server.  I have simplified the test case to the point  that it must be a problem with system setup.  I am a developer and have very little experience with server administration, so I must be missing something obvious.  The server is on Digital Ocean with standard setup for MEAN on Ubuntu.  I haven't changed much in the server setup.  Where should I look?

Here is the node server code (it's the real code that is running):

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');

var app = express();

var rcount=0;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('--'+rcount+':'+req.protocol+'://' + req.headers.host + req.originalUrl);
  rcount++;
  next();
});

app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/js'), {maxAge: 86400000})); 

http.createServer(app).listen(9876, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port 9876');
});
```

Here is what happens under siege (sorry for length, but it is needed to see the picture).  The logger on the server side shows that express DID NOT receive the requests that timed out. In the testing environment, there are no proxies or anything, node runs directly on 9876 as shown.

```
MacBook-Air-alex:www alex$ siege -iv http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9876/js/animatescroll.js
** SIEGE 3.0.7
** Preparing 15 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
HTTP/1.1 200   0.10 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.11 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.11 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.12 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.12 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.10 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.11 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.11 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.14 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.12 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.11 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.10 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.12 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.12 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.10 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.11 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.14 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
[error] socket: 209698816 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 212381696 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 208089088 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 207015936 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 209162240 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
HTTP/1.1 200   0.14 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
[error] socket: 208625664 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 205942784 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 206479360 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 205406208 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 211308544 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
[error] socket: 210771968 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.14 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.15 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.11 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.40 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
[error] socket: 210235392 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
HTTP/1.1 200   0.19 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
[error] socket: 204869632 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
HTTP/1.1 200   0.11 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.16 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.16 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.17 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.10 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.12 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.14 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
[error] socket: 211845120 connection timed out.: Operation timed out
HTTP/1.1 200   0.12 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.12 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
HTTP/1.1 200   0.13 secs:    7686 bytes ==> GET  /js/animatescroll.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a datacenter problem.  Diagnosed by running a copy of the server in a different datacenter.

I didn't even get to complain, it was fixed by the time I figured it out.   Cost me 3 days.  Thanks, Digital Ocean!